# Does a weapon with a percent of its damage returned as life proc from spells or melee hits only?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a weapon on my wizard that converts a small portion of damage dealt to life.
Does this work for spell damage I do, or only on melee hits?

Answer (score 1):

It works for spell damage as well as melee damage - the game is very much focused on you using your spells moreso than your weapons.

My Witch Doctor favors equipment with this enchantment - high DPS attacks can keep him alive in even the most challenging areas.

The [Diablo 3 Wikia](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Life_Steal) states:

> Life and Mana steal only work on Melee, and physical ranged attacks.

I believe this means that only abilities that do a percentage of your weapon damage count, which would line up with my experiences so far.